# Can the Coral USB Accelerator work with a Linux VM?

Tags: virtual-machine

I've seen the intel Movidius Neural compute stick state they will work with a linux VM, but I don't know that the Coral USB accelerator will. Can I assume most USB devices are accessible from a VM?

I want to play with tensorflow in a VM environment, but it doesn't seem like GPU can be accessed without special hardware / virtualization tools. So I'm wondering what "devices" could be attached to make a work around for this.

Comment: USB passthrough and GPU are two different and independent issues in a VM.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking into this for years and unfortunately there is no "official" support yet to be able to do this on Hyper-V even in the latest 2019 release.

It is also [Unsupported](https://forums.docker.com/t/connect-usb-devices-to-windows-docker-container/73200/4) in Docker on Windows Server 2019 as well.

However, there is a 3rd party solution called [USB-Redirector](https://www.net-usb.com/usb-redirector/) 
but at $139 for the license, better off just buying a Raspberry pi 4 with 4GB of RAM and a fancy case, heatsinks sand fans for cheaper than that which is what I will probably end up doing myself. I'm just undecided with the compute stick 2 VS the coral to build something with. I'd LIKE for Microsoft to add support for this and I refuse to rebuild everything in ESXi again just for this feature as Hyper-V is better for the majority of my uses.

Another Free option is [USB/IP Project](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) but it is from 2011 so I'm not sure I would even bother since many people write about unnecessary delays between the device and the destination. Worth a look if you already have the compute stick and let us know how well it does or doesn’t work.

For the [GPU passthrough](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/deploy/deploying-graphics-devices-using-dda), it depends but it can be done but it's 1 PCIe card passed directly to 1 VM. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/HyperV/comments/5tnnz8/hyperv_2016_pcigpu_passthrough_successfully/) someone was able to pass a consumer card through to a VM, but it was a Windows VM and it was an ATI card. If you have the hardware, it's worth a shot. If you will be buying a card for this, someone already did a LOT of [research](https://timdettmers.com/2019/04/03/which-gpu-for-deep-learning/) on this and has benchmarks for various cards, pro's and con's. Let us know what path and stack you end up using and how it performs if you get it all working.

Comment: I pursued requesting Linux machines on my company's corporate network. This has been a multi-month ordeal that I'm hoping is finished soon. (Read, I don't have a linux machine on network yet).